# Facebook Events, Set Category Field Missing

Tags: facebook

I am trying to set up a page-hosted event via the Facebook frontend, not via the api. I recently heard about a "category" field that should be available as of graph api v2.4. A perfect way to sort my events by topic, I thought by myself.

However, the desired option is just not there in the Facebook frontend. Every other field is available, such as Ticket-URI, Tags, etc.

Am I missing something here? Is the category field restricted to specific countries (Germany is speaking) or has the field been deprecated?

Thanks in advance for enlightening me.